# Move everything a little bit left in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning

I am putting an image in each column on a slide, everything is perfect except that because the first image starts too far right and it pushes a small part of the second image off the slide. How can I move where the images begin a little to the left so the entire images are included on the slide? Here is my code, again it would fit but it starts too far to the right on the slide.

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Trends in total Events}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}

\includegraphics[scale=.4]{eventsgraph1.pdf}

\column{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{eventsgraph2.pdf}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\hspace` with a negativ length to shift the picture to the left. Pay attention: you must not have a blank line between `\hspace` and `\includegraphics`

```
\column{.5\textwidth}
    \hspace{-1cm}
    \includegraphics[scale=.4]{eventsgraph1.pdf}
```

You could also automatically resize the picture according the available space:

```
 \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=.7\textheight,keepaspectratio]{eventsgraph1.pdf}
```